# TV show with aliens living in a small stone?

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

I am looking for the name of a science fiction TV show from the late 70ies or early 80ies.

In the show small aliens used a fist-sized rock as their ship to explore their environment here on earth. A detail that I remember was that the rock had something like a periscope to observe the outside world. The key plot element of using the stone was to be very stealthy but unfortunately I can't remember more specific details.

While watching Portlandia ([Season 2, Episode 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmitvXIamFc)) I think the 'alien fruit' might be a reference to that TV show but I am not absolutely certain and googling did not provide any further hints.

Answer (score 4):

That sounds like the TV movie Invasion from 1997. The rocks can inject people with an enzyme that activates genes already inserted into human DNA which begins converting the people into aliens. The injected people then start building a portal to bring alien ships to Earth.

Comment: And the small stone?

Comment: By rocks I meant small stones. They fall from the sky and are all over town. When people pick them up they get injected with the enzyme. Scientists examine one of them and find out there are aliens inside the stones.

Comment: Hmm, I am certain that the show aired several years before 1997. Additionally from the trailer this looks almost like a horror movie while the few bits that I remember felt much more like exploration and discovery than conquering.